# reference request: image set of polynomial iteration in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $x = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f_{i}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be polynomials (of coordinates). Let $F :\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n = (f_1,\ldots,f_n)$.

For some $x$ and $F$, one can plot the scatter plots of $I(x) = \{ F^{(k)}(x) \}_{k\ge 1}$ (where $F^{(k)}$ mean iterations) and somehow guess that the image looks like a bounded region of certain form. One will then want to prove that $I(x)$ is dense in that region.

EDIT: Someone asked for a (non-trivial) example. Try $n=2$ with

$$f_1(x,y) = y^2-2x-4, f_2(x,y) = x, F=(f_1,f_2), (x_0,y_0)=(3/4,2).$$

The scatter plot will look like

[image]

and one can easily prove that the absolute value of each coordinate of the points is less than 4.

Which branch of mathematics systematically studies this kind of question? I kind of recall that people talk about function iterations in dynamical systems, and there is also something called ergodic theory, but I failed to find references that directly connect them with the question above.

Comment: What do you mean by $F^{(k)}$? this notation suggests derivation. Is it $k$ times iterate?

Comment: What topology do you use? Zariski's or usual? And do you have examples for $n=1$ or $n=2$? I don't get why it would be bounded (e.g. $F(x) = x^2, \, x = 2$)

Comment: You mean like Fatou and Julia sets? "Dynamics of one complex variable" (Milnor), "Iterations of rational maps" (rational instead of polynomial to include useful things like the Newton iteration), "moduli spaces", "hyperbolic components" are titles and keywords in that direction.

Comment: @JulesBesson it wont be always bounded. The other way to ask this is given x and F, what can one say about the closure of the images of all the iterations

Comment: Ok I think @LutzLehmann gave you a good answer then